# How to implement cross-platform cscope-like text-based user interface?

Tags: c++, user-interface, cscope

I want my C++ program to:

- Allow the selection of choices as in cscope; that is using tabs, and circularly iterating over the choices.
- Further, the choices should not scroll, as is the case with cscope.

Any ideas how I can implement this? I would like my implementation to be cross-platform i.e. supports Windows, Linux and Mac environments.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). Have a look at the Linux tool `aptitude` to see what it can look like.